# GS3 automatically answering incoming calls

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, calls

Why is my GS3 automatically answering incoming calls. I am not using a headset/bluetooth.
The phone can be in an entirely different room when a call is automatically answered.

Answer (score 2):

Is your Settings > Language And Input > Voice Command for Apps 'On'?
Sometimes it picks up something in the background and answers the calls.

If turning off that doesn't work, try to do a [factory reset](http://droidlessons.com/how-to-factory-reset-the-samsung-galaxy-s3/) on the phone.

Unfortunately, if even that doesn't work, you will have to get it inspected at a Service Center.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting a 3.5 Headphones with mic and call your cell.

If it will answer automatically it is a software problem, try to remember what things have you changed/installed before that was happend.

If it fix the problem, take out the Headphones and try calling your cell.
Sometimes the AUX 3.5 Jack isn't recognizing when a device is plugged-out (mostly because of a damaged headphones/headphone's Jack), this could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

On my T-Mobile SGH-T999 Galaxy S3 (Android 4.1.1), there is a "S Voice" icon under Apps. If you start the app and skip the setup questions, you will be prompted "***What would you like to do?***".

At this point press the menu button and choose ***Settings*** > *Control apps*, turn off "*Control apps: Use voice commands to control device*".

Hope that helps!