# Galaxy S5 answers calls automatically

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, calls, samsung-galaxy-s-5

I'm not sure if there is a setting or if this is a bug, but my Verizon Galaxy S5 has auto answered incoming calls on at least three occasions. The phone is usually on my desk when it happens and no other devices are connected to it (no usb, no charger). I also don't have any apps on my phone that should be answering by themselves. I've had 10+ other non-samsung android phones and I've never had this happen before, so I'm a little concerned and not interested in having an "open" mic.

Very similar to this S3 question, but I don't think its a dupe since its different devices and android versions. [GS3 automatically answering incoming calls](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/37472/gs3-automatically-answering-incoming-calls)

Comment: This is probably going to be a long shot, but do you by any chance wave your hand over the phone when it is ringing? There is a setting under settings > accessibility > answering and ending calls

Comment: I was only close to it once out of the total times, but I'll check that setting anyhow, thank you

Comment: The option to answer via wave of a hand was not enabled; thanks for pointing me at this option set, I didn't know it was available.

Comment: I only found out when looking at your issue, there is also a similar function to wake up your device which is also pretty good! Sorry couldn't help out more with your situation. Only thing I can suggest is putting your phone into recovery mode (hold power, home button, volume up button all at once when your phone is off) and navigate to clear cashe and reboot phone to see if it has worked